# Can I play online in Minecraft: Wii U?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-legacy-console

In *Minecraft: Wii U*, I have a survival world and a creative build / experiment world, and I also like playing around with the tutorial world. But is it possible to play online (servers) in *Minecraft: Wii U?*

Comment: What type of server? Big servers like mineplex or personal servers or Minecraft realms?

Comment: Big servers like Mineplex and Hypixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but you can't!

Joining servers hasn't been brought to the Wii U quite yet.

> You can only join a server from a friend or a friend of your friend :)

[Source](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-wii-u-edition/mcwiiu-discussion/2582596-how-to-join-a-server)

You can still play with your friends though!